# C++ Using a Binary search tree to sort a file of numbers

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, nodes

Ive made this program that uses a BST algorithm to go through a file containing 50 integer values and then display them using in-order traversal

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>

 std::string fileName; 
 std::fstream readFile;
 int storeFile;

struct Node {
     int data;
     Node* left;
     Node* right;
};

struct bstNode {
     int data;
     bstNode* left;
     bstNode* right;
};

bstNode* getnewNode(int data) {
      bstNode* newNode = new bstNode();
      (*newNode).data = data;
      (*newNode).left = NULL;
      (*newNode).right = NULL;
      return newNode;
}

     bstNode* Insert(bstNode* root,int data) {
     if(root == NULL) {
      root = getnewNode(data);
      return root;
     } else if( data <= root->data) {
          root->left = Insert(root->left,data);
     } 
     else {
          root->right = Insert(root->right,data);
     }
     return root;
}

bool Search(bstNode* root, int data) {

if(root == NULL ) {
     return false;
} else if(root->data == data) {
     return true;
} else if(data <= root->data)  {
     return Search(root->left, data);
} else return Search(root->right,data);
}

void Inorder(bstNode* root) {
     if(root==NULL) return;
     Inorder(root->left);
     std::cout << root->data << std::endl;
     Inorder(root->right);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   bstNode* root = NULL;
   std::cout << "Please enter the name of the file: " <<  std::endl; //prompts user for the filename
   std::cin >> argv[0];  //stores the filename is the first element of argv[]

   fileName = argv[0];

   std::cout << "Attempting to read file " << fileName <<  std::endl;

   readFile.open(fileName); //attempts to read the file

  if(!readFile) {
       std::cerr << "ERROR: failed to open file " <<  std::endl;  //if the file cannot be opened an error is displayed
      exit(0); //if it cannot open the console terminates
      } else {
           std::cerr << "File successfully opened" <<  std::endl;
    
      }

       while(readFile >> storeFile){
          if(readFile.bad()) {
               std::cerr << "File failed to read " << std:: endl;
              break; //loop terminates
                } else {
               
                    root = Insert(root, storeFile);      
                                
         } 
           Inorder(root); 
    }

readFile.close();     
 return 0;  
}
```

The program compiles correctly and can run, however i dont think the output is correct

input file

```
1
12
10
7
2
9
4
100
```

output

```
1
1
12
1
10
12
1
7
10
12
1
2
7
10
12
1
2
7
9
10
12
1
2
4
7
9
10
12
1
2
4
7
9
10
12
100
```

I know this output is not correct as its way too large. Where abouts in my prorgram am I going wrong with using BST? thankyou

Comment: First of all try to minimize the input set. That will make it easier to use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement to see what really happens.

Comment: By the way, why `std::cin >> argv[0]`? Why do you use `argv[0]` as temporary storage of the file-name? What if the length of the input is larger than the current string pointed to by `argv[0]`? Why don't you input directly into `fileName` (`std::cin >> fileName`)? And why is `fileName` (along with `readFile` and `storeFile`) a global variable?

Comment: Your input loop also skips every other line as you call `>>` twice.

Comment: You call `InOrder` every time you read a number. You should only call it once. Please learn how to [debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) like this.

Comment: @Botje ah so if i remove the second ```>>``` from the else it shoould be good?

Comment: Fix both the issues I showed and you should be closer to a solution. If it is still not correct, try with smaller inputs as @Someprogrammerdude said. You can generate all 120 permutations of 1--5 and run them through your program; the output should always be 1--5.

Comment: @Botje Ive fixed both issues if you'd like to reread the code/question.

Comment: `(*newNode).data` is better written as `newNode->data`; other than that, check if your editor/IDE has an "autoformat" command and use it vigorously.

Comment: @Botje other than that is my output correct?

Comment: Of course the output is not correct! You pass in a list of 8 numbers and you get back a lot more. Had you fixed your indentation, you would see that the `InOrder` call is still in the scope of your `while` loop, and it is thus still called for every number that you read.

Comment: @Botje thanks for your help. I managed to get it working properly :)